# Looping through Spreadsheet to collect data starting with xxx_bb

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script

I am confused about the following task. 
Eventually, I want to find certain data in a spreadsheet. 
This is not a problem, I can find a defined value and grab whatever information I need around it through:

```
function findCell() {
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
       var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('NAME');
       var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
       var values = dataRange.getValues();

       for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
         var row = "";
         for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {     
           if (values[i][j] == "Hallo") {
             row = values[i][j+11];
             Logger.log(row);
             Logger.log(i);
             }
           }       
     } 
  }
```

But I am not trying to find the exact value "Hallo" but anything starting with "Hallo_xxx". I tried to use i.e. indexOf but I am not sure what I am doing wrong - this task doesn't sound too difficult to solve. Does anybody got a good idea here...?

Thanks for your advice, 
Sa

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I just wrote and tested. findCell() should do what you want. As you surmised, indexOf() will quickly find specific text within a string, but I don't see where you tried to use it in your code.

```
var ROW = 0;
var COLUMN = 1;

function test(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var results = findCell("Hallo_xxx", sheet);

  for(var i=0 ; i<results.length ; i++){
    Logger.log("Match found at: " + colToA1(results[i][COLUMN]) + (results[i][ROW] + 1));
  }
}

function findCell(string, sheet) {
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();  
  var results = [];

  for(var i=0 ; i<values.length ; i++){
    for(var j=0 ; j<values[0].length ; j++){
      if(values[i][j].indexOf(string) != -1){
        results.push([i, j]);
      }
    }
  }

  return results;  
}

function colToA1(col){
  return col < 26 ? 
    String.fromCharCode(col + 65) : 
    String.fromCharCode(parseInt(col / 26) + 64) + String.fromCharCode((col % 26) + 65);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on this a bit, the answer I was looking for is:

```
function findCell2() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Name');
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();


 for(var i=1;i<values.length;i++){
 if((values[i][1].indexOf('Hallo') >  -1){
            Logger.log('xxx: ' + values[i][2]);
  }
}  
}
```